# Python Pandas CSV import / Unicode woes

Tags: python, csv, pandas, classification

I am working with message board posts (contained in `CSV` files), trying to clean data/etc, before training classification models.

Things were going well, until I got:

> TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable

in response to the line:

```
letters_only = ''.join([i for i in textToProcess if not i.isdigit()])
```

Where textToProcess comes from `(train["text"][i])`.

So... when I thought to check on my data by making calls to:

```
print train.isnull().sum()
print test.isnull().sum()
```

I got the following output:

```
id          0
category    0
title       0
text        1
train       26
dtype:      int64
id          5512
category    5512
title       5512
text        5512
train       5512
dtype: int64
```

**Question**: So I take this to mean that in the test set, there are 5512 null values in every column?

This would be odd, since the imports, etc. appeared to be behaving as expected for the most part until this point. For example, calls to e.g. `train["text"][0]` produced the expected output (namely text).

In case it helps, my original read_csv import calls looked like:

```
train = pd.read_csv(full_train_filename, header=0, encoding = 'utf-8')

test = pd.read_csv(full_test_filename, header=0, encoding = 'utf-8')`
```

I'm not sure there is a single direct question here, but am hoping that someone sees something I've done wrong.

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is possible share your `csv`s if not confidental?

Comment: Unfortunately, I think it does count as confidential. Anything in particular you'd look for? I can have take a peek and report back.

Comment: Yep. Default is ",", from pandas docs:

Comment: Actually, here is an excerpt from the the documentation for read_csv  from pandas:

sep : str, default ‘,’
Delimiter to use. If sep is None, will try to automatically determine this. Separators longer than 1 character and different from ‘s+’ will be interpreted as regular expressions, will force use of the python parsing engine and will ignore quotes in the data. Regex example: ‘rt’

Comment: Hmmm, if question is why are `NaN` values in `csv`, then I think you need check this problematic rows - use `print (df[df.isnull().any(1)])` - filter all rows where is at least one NaN value in some column.

Comment: Okay. In line with the earlier output, using print (test[test.isnull().any(1)]) prints all rows as NaN. However, using print test["train"][0] produces the expected text.

Comment: What is `print (df.shape)`?

Comment: test.shape: 
(8001, 5)

Which is odd. I would have expected 5212. Have to go for now, and got a warning about avoiding extended discussions in comments :P

Comment: I think you can check your csv in some editor like `Notepad++`, I think there is a lot of empty rows.

Comment: Thanks a million. I had a bunch of trailing rows, and removing them solved my issue. Not sure why I didn't think of that, but am glad you did!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need check `NaN` values in your `DataFrame`, which is created from `csv`. You can use [`isnull`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.isnull.html) with [`any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) and [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
test[test.isnull().any(1)]
```

Sample:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

test = pd.DataFrame({'a': {0: 'r', 1: 'r', 2: 't', 3: 'y'}, 
                     'b': {0: 'a', 1: 'a', 2: 's', 3: 'g'}, 
                     'c': {0: 7.0, 1: 5.0, 2: np.nan, 3: 4.0}})
print (test)
   a  b    c
0  r  a  7.0
1  r  a  5.0
2  t  s  NaN
3  y  g  4.0

print (test[test.isnull().any(1)])
   a  b   c
2  t  s NaN
```

Then you can use some text editor e.g. `Notepad++` and check this problematic rows.

Comment: The issue ended up being that there were many (trailing) empty rows in the test data set. This was the reason for the call to print test.isnull().sum() returning such a large number. So I manually removed these trailing values using notepad, and used train = train.dropna() and test=test.dropna() to remove the rest of the missing values. This seems to have worked. Now on to the exciting part - data analysis! Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Glad can help you. Nice day!